# pdfVIew doesn't work on my kotlin development environment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, pdf, pdfview

I put some pdf files to test pdf loading from external storage and made a code following :

[image]

The code is :

```
val main_path = "/storage/emulated/0/"
val dl_path = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS
val filename = "GLCIC.pdf"
val filename2 = "edge.pdf"
private val img_path = Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
private val mv_path = Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    if(checkPermission(Storage_Permission,Flag_Permission_storage)){
        Log.d("check","Permission Granted")
    }


    val intent = Intent(this,ViewActivity::class.java)
    val intent_store = Intent(this,ViewActivity::class.java)
    btn1.setOnClickListener {
        intent.putExtra("pressed","asset")
        startActivity(intent) }

    btn2.setOnClickListener {
        intent_store.putExtra("pdf",main_path+dl_path+"/"+filename2)
        startActivity(intent_store)
```

This is a code in mainActivity and pressing btn2 will pass an Intent to viewActivity.

```
val pressed2 = intent.getStringExtra("pdf")
    Log.d("1","112:"+pressed2.toString())
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(pressed2))
    {
        Log.d("1","11:"+pressed2.toString())
        val pdf_file = File(pressed2)
        pdfview.fromFile(pdf_file)
    }
```

This is code in viewActivity.

This code made a log :

```
D/1: 112:/storage/emulated/0/Download/edge.pdf
11:/storage/emulated/0/Download/edge.pdf
```

Judging from the log I don't think that I made any mistake, but the pdfview did not work, showing the white screen .

Please somebody tell me where I made mistake. I really want to load a file, or make a list of files in a directory. But I am mazed for few weeks.

Comment: How did you put those files in Download folder?

Comment: Please post your code as text.

Comment: @blackapps  Thanks for your help and I added code

Comment: Please dont post images. Only text. Remove the image. You could also just tell how you placed the images there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the text color is white.
Try setting the text color to **Black**,
I made this mistake once and I had set the text color to **White** by mistake, so maybe it could work.

And if its not the text color then please upload the entire code.